# Javascript dynamic condition execution

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a dynamic JavaScript condition execution.

For example, I have a JSON object like...

```js
let Obj = {
    a:15,
    b:20,
    c:"String",
    d:1
}
```

And I have the following predefined condition...

```js
let expression = "a==15 && b==20 && c.startsWith('S') && d>0";
```

I want to execute the expression and that should resolve to `true/false` by passing actual values from the JSON object.

In example above, it should resolve to `true`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show that a good faith effort has been made to solve the problem. Show us what you tried, what is working or not.

Comment: The function you are looking for is eval() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval
however, @radarbob is correct, you need to include the code you have tried to use to solve this problem, and ask any specific questions arising from that attempt.

Comment: @CamM that's just mean...

Comment: `if(Obj.a === 15){ /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: `function expression (o) { return o.a === 15 && o.b === 20 && o.c.startsWith('S') && o.d > 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could always try building a dynamic function (slightly better than `eval()`). You'll have to convert your `Obj` into some variable declarations.

```
const fn = new Function(`
  ${Object
    .entries(Obj)
    .map(([key, value]) => `const ${key} = ${JSON.stringify(value)};`)
    .join('\n')
  }
  return ${expression};
`)
console.log(fn());
```